# How I can have a custom Toast with a public static class

Tags: android, toast

I created the following so as to control the several cases of toast messages

```
public class ExtraUtils {

public static Activity MyActivity;
public static LayoutInflater mInflater;

public static void MyToast(View view,int ToastCase) 
{
    Context context=MyActivity.getApplicationContext();
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View customToastroot =mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
    Toast customtoast=new Toast(context);
    TextView text = (TextView) customToastroot.findViewById(R.id.txtToast);
    // Set the Text to show in TextView
    switch(ToastCase)
    {
        case 1:
            text.setText("You cannot Select this Again");
            break;
        case 2:
            text.setText("Oops Something went wrong");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

And I call it like ExtraUtils.MyToast(view,1) but I get a null exception at

```
Context context=MyActivity.getApplicationContext();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`Context context = MyActivity.getApplicationContext();`

to

`Context context = MyActivity.this;`

**Edit**

Sorry, I thought you are writing the code in the MyActivity itself. What you need to do is,

```
public static void MyToast(View view,int ToastCase, Context context)
```

and in MyActivity from where you are calling it do,

```
 ExtraUtils.MyToast(view, 1, MyActivity.this)
```

Comment: When I type it, It says class name expected in the point of MyActivity

Comment: same answer i was gonna post but saw your answer. Nice work @MiaoulisNikos

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work!!! **MyActivity** is not **initialized** ...

Send the content inside the parameter

```
public static void MyToast(Content context,View view,int ToastCase) {
    // Context context=MyActivity.getApplicationContext();
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View customToastroot =mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
    Toast customtoast=new Toast(context);
    TextView text = (TextView) customToastroot.findViewById(R.id.txtToast);
    // Set the Text to show in TextView
    switch(ToastCase) {
        case 1:
            text.setText("You cannot Select this Again");
            break;
        case 2:
            text.setText("Oops Something went wrong");
            break;
    }
   //...Write Code for display toast
}
```